# Write list to .txt file separating everything with a comma

Tags: c#, command-line, io

I want to write a list to a .txt file, with every value separated by a comma.

The file looks exactly like this:

```
John,12,45,2019,09,16,2
José Carlos,12,30,2019,09,15,2
```

The code shown here is reading the file and sending the values to the list, what I wanted is to write to the file so it looks like the above example.

I have no clue of how to do it.

```
string line;

StreamReader file = new StreamReader("marcacoes.txt");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(',');
    string nome = words[0];
    int horas = Int32.Parse(words[1]);
    int minutos = Int32.Parse(words[2]);
    int ano = Int32.Parse(words[3]);
    int mes = Int32.Parse(words[4]);
    int dia = Int32.Parse(words[5]);
    int campo = Int32.Parse(words[6]);

    listaMarcacoes.Add(new marcacoes(nome, horas, minutos, new DateTime(ano, mes, dia), campo));
}
```

The class looks like this:

```
public string NomeCliente { get => nomeCliente; set => nomeCliente = value;}
public int Hora { get => hora; set => hora = value; }
public int Minutos { get => minutos; set => minutos = value; }
public DateTime Data { get => data; set => data = value; }
public int Campo { get => campo; set => campo = value; }
```

Comment: `string.Format("{0},{1},{2},....", name, etc, etc, ...)` ? or with $ => `$"{name},{etc},{etc}..."` Where is the problem?

Comment: @Selvin I was just being 100% dumb ._. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can `Join` the required properties into `string`:

```
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq;

...

List<marcacoes> list = ...

File.WriteAllLines("marcacoes.txt", list
  .Select(item => string.Join(",", // join with "," following properties:
     item.Nome,                
     item.Hora,
     item.Minutos,
     item.Data.Year,
     item.Data.Month,
     item.Data.Day,
     item.Campo)));
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with the ``` File.WriteLines..``` the WriteLines doesn't exist

Comment: @BernardoPiedade: I'm sorry for the typo, it should be `WriteAllLines`